# Learn MacRuby or Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macruby

Well, my fisrt question was a bit too general so i ll try again and hope this one is better.
The way i see it is:
Ruby->MacRuby or IronRuby or Rails
Obj-c->Mac Development

So Ruby has clearly more potential in desktop and web platforms and now with MacRuby, OSX native (and commercial) apps are on the way. If i get it wrong please correct me.

For me that i will do a fresh start should i go with the modern Ruby or start learning c+obj-c?
Will a newcomer benefit much (in learning & coding time, frustration, complexity) by learning/using macruby for osx apps rather objective-c? Or its pretty much the same?
I hope some day to hang around here and help others.

Comment: Maybe it would help the OP to decide if there is a list of well-known Mac applications that is developed in MacRuby (i.e., a showcase of here is what MacRuby can do).

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you learn both.

If you're serious about native Mac OS X development, it certainly won't hurt to learn Objective-C and Cocoa (as it's the canonical environment).

Comment: Agreed. While MacRuby might let you develop decent Cocoa Apps, 99.9% of the samples and help for all of the OSX libraries and frameworks all assume objective C, so you at least need to understand it well enough to grok those

Answer (score 1):

There was a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505968) recently. I’ve already answered there – the point is that Objective-C is the only first-class citizen when it comes to developing Mac and iPhone apps and it will probably stay that way. I’d learn both, the more languages you know the better programmer you are. (With a certain license.)

Answer (score 0):

What languages do you know now?

If you already know Java or C#, learning Ruby in the form of JRuby or Iron Ruby is a no-brainer. You can use them for any number of tasks around the edges of what you already know and decide if you like it.

Comment: No languages yet. I would go obj-c, the native as others suggest, but since Ruby(MacRuby) is said to be easier code/read/learn i am in this dilemma.

Comment: I don't think ObjC makes for a good first language. Ruby might be a better first language as you can make use of irb (or macirb) to experiment with it interactively.